# Relationship among secrecy-constant, key space and message space

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

Here scheme $\Pi$ is $\epsilon $ -
perfectly secret.
Given that encryption scheme $\Pi$ =  $(\mathrm{Gen}, \mathrm{Enc}, \mathrm{Dec})$ over $(\mathcal K,\mathcal M,\mathcal C)$ is called $\epsilon $ -
perfectly secret if for any distribution over $\mathcal M$, any $m \in  M $ and any $ c \in C$,

$|Pr[M=m|C=c] - Pr[M=m]|<\epsilon$

then how to prove that ,
$|\mathcal K|\geq (1 - \epsilon)|\mathcal M|$

I am not getting idea how to proceed as here $\epsilon$ can be anything i.e non-negligible or negligible both.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: here you can prove the above thing by contradiction. Start with the reverse of what needs to be proved and see you can arrive at contradiction or not. Treat $\epsilon$ as a parameter any, by the way, you are right it can be anything negligible or non-negligible.

Comment: Prove by contradiction is nice idea, let's see whether I am able to reach final result or not. Thanks, Sam for quick response.